# Bounce Back on AVR External Interrupt

Tags: c, interrupt, avr

It works now!!

In the process of cropping the code to post here, it seems I removed the logical error that was making my pin bounce back. My Bad... here's the code for your reference:-

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

ISR (INT1_vect)
{

ext_int1();
}

int ext_int1(void)
{

PORTD|=(1<<PD5);
}


int main(void) {

DDRD=0xF0;
PORTD=0xFF;
PORTD&=~(1<<PD5);
uint16_t a=0;

GICR|=(1<<INT1); // enable external interrupt INT1

sei();

while(1){

a=1;
a=2;
}

}
```

The previous problem is as below, thanks everyone for your patience & help.

I have a problem in Atmel ATMEGA8 while using external Interrupt INT1. The interrupt is set to when INT1 is LOW. Calling the interrupt is supposed to turn ON a pin PD6.

Now the problem is that if I declare PD6 as LOW, the pin reverts to LOW state when the interrupt condition is removed. But if I do not declare PD6, then the program works fine.

The code is as below:-

```
ISR INT1_vect()
{
PORTD|=(1<<PD6);
}

int main (void)

{

DDRD=0xF0;
PORTD|=(1<<PD3); // enabling pull up resistor for INT1


PORTD&=~(1<<PD6); // initialise PD6 to LOW
GICR|=(1<<INT1);
sei();

.
.
.
```

I have used other Interrupts for PWM (compare & over flow) & ADC (conversion complete) and they are working fine. I use PWM interrupts to run the PWM on digital output ports.

What happens can be summed up below:-

INT1          PD6

Open          LOW

GND           HIGH

Open          LOW (if initialised in main())

Comment: Please be more specific and you should post the full code (at least the full main()). Do you use a level triggered interrupt? What means "if I do not declare PD6, then the program works fine". What do you declare where?

Comment: Yes I am using a level triggered interrupt i.e. the interrupt gets triggered when INT1 is at 0 volts.

Also my entire code also consists of PWM mechanics & ADC reading which controls the PWM. I have not posted the entire code as I thought it would be irrelevant & confuse people even more.

Comment: Also I initialised PD6 by the below line:-
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD6);

Comment: show your full code of an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 0):

Pin 6 on PORTD should not go low again unless you are setting it low somewhere else.

If you are not setting it low anywhere except at the start of `main()`, then that indicates that the system is resetting itself and running `main()` again. An enabled interrupt without a handler could cause that. Check to make sure the system is not crashing.